# Laravel/javascript Modal fail to appear

Tags: laravel

is there anything wrong with my `id=submit_fw` in the blade, the modal did not appear and I already addressed it to the text/javascript below, the button will submit the data in the show.blade and it supposed to have a confirmation message.

show blade

```
<div class="col-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 p-0 mt-0"></div>
            @if($fw->fw_current_stg == "UR" && $fw->fw_user == $user)
                <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 p-0 mt-0 text-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block  text-white" id="submit_fw">
                    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" id="sp_submit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <i class="fas fa-check" id="icon_submit"></i> SUBMIT REQUEST
                    </button>
            @endif
```

text/javascript

```
$('#submit_fw').click(function()
{
    $('#sp_submit').removeClass('d-none');
    $('#icon_submit').addClass('d-none');


    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Proceed PR?', 
        text: 'Are you sure you want to submit this PR to Department Head?',
        icon:'question',
        confirmButtonText: 'YES',
        confirmButtonColor: '#fa0031',
        cancelButtonColor: '#fa0031',
        showCancelButton:'true',
        cancelButtonText:'NO',  
        }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('fw.submitfw')}}",
                type:"post",
                data:{
                    fw_number:$('#fw_number').val(),
                },
                success: function(result){
                    if(result == "submitted")
                    {
                        Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Success',
                        text: 'Your PR has been submitted to your Department Head',
                        icon: 'success',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Return to List',
                        confirmButtonColor: '#fa0031',
                        }).then((result) => {
                            if (result.value) {
                                let url = "{{route('fw.index')}}";
                                document.location.href=url;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });     
        }
        else 
        {
            
        }
        });

    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check `id=submit_fw` is only one time used in your blade file.
Then you simply set addEventListener to the id.

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit_fw');
var submitUrl = "{{route('fw.submitfw')}}";

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#sp_submit').removeClass('d-none');
  $('#icon_submit').addClass('d-none');
  submitButton.disabled = true;

  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Proceed PR?', 
    text: 'Are you sure you want to submit this PR to Department Head?',
    icon:'question',
    confirmButtonText: 'YES',
    confirmButtonColor: '#fa0031',
    cancelButtonColor: '#fa0031',
    showCancelButton:'true',
    cancelButtonText:'NO',  
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      $.ajax({
        url: submitUrl,
        type:"post",
        data:{
            fw_number:$('#fw_number').val(),
        },
        success: function(result){
            if(result == "submitted") {
              $('#sp_submit').addClass('d-none');
              $('#icon_submit').removeClass('d-none');
              submitButton.disabled = false;
              Swal.fire({
              title: 'Success',
              text: 'Your PR has been submitted to your Department Head',
              icon: 'success',
              confirmButtonText: 'Return to List',
              confirmButtonColor: '#fa0031',
              }).then((result) => {
                  if (result.value) {
                      let url = "{{route('fw.index')}}";
                      document.location.href=url;
                  }
              });
            } else {
              Swal.fire({
                text: 'Somthing went wrong, please try agian!',
                icon: "error",
                confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                confirmButtonColor: '#fa0031',
              });
              $('#sp_submit').addClass('d-none');
              $('#icon_submit').removeClass('d-none');
              submitButton.disabled = false;
            }
          },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $('#sp_submit').addClass('d-none');
          $('#icon_submit').removeClass('d-none');
          submitButton.disabled = false;
        }
      });     
    } else {
      $('#sp_submit').addClass('d-none');
      $('#icon_submit').removeClass('d-none');
      submitButton.disabled = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Excellent!, This is my day.

Comment: Excellent, It's helped me more